# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with fetch POST method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, fetch

I get this warning when i use my fetch post method how can I  cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.With my Post methods.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { UPLOAD_PRESET, CLOUD_NAME, SERVER_API } from "../../config";

const uploadImage = async (file) => {
  const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${CLOUD_NAME}/upload`;
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  formData.append("upload_preset", UPLOAD_PRESET);

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Can't upload image. ${res.status}`);
  }

  const data = await res.json();
  return await data.eager[0].secure_url;
};

const createAlbum = async (data) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${SERVER_API}/api/v1/albums`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`An error has occurred: ${res.status}`);
  }

  const json = await res.json();
  return json.data._id;
};

const Form = ({ file, loading, setError, album, color, children }) => {
  let history = useHistory();

  const clearError = () => setError("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    clearError();
    try {
      if (!file) {
        throw new Error("Please select a file to add.");
      }

      if (!album.trim("") || !color.trim()) {
        throw new Error("Please enter all the field values.");
      }

      loading(true);

      const fileUrl = await uploadImage(file);

      const data = {
        name: album,
        bckImgUrl: fileUrl,
        color: color,
      };

      const albumId = await createAlbum(data);

      history.push(`/albums/${albumId}`);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      loading(false);
    }
  };
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{children}</form>;
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: that is a warning... not an error

Comment: i see but how to fix it

Comment: you are showing only the functions to call the api, not how, or when you are calling them

Comment: if u scroll down code its in handleSubmit function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ramesh on using a ref. I figured I'd show how it could be extracted out into a custom hook.

```js
function useHasUnmountedRef() {
  const hasUnmountedRef = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      hasUnmountedRef.current = true;
    }
  }, []);
  return hasUnmountedRef;
}

function Form() {

  const hasUnmountedRef = useHasUnmountedRef();

  const handleSubmit = async () => {

    await asyncStuff();

    if (hasUnmountedRef.current) {
      // escape early because component has unmounted
      return;
    }

    // Thanks to the guard clause above, you can guarantee at this
    // point that your component is still mounted. You can perform
    // state updates without generating a React warning. 
    //
    // If you do another "await" however, you will need to check
    // again. Everytime you await something async, there is a chance
    // that the component could have unmounted while waiting for the
    // async stuff to complete.

  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Your custom hook isn't returning anything. I'll edit that.

Comment: Maybe its dumb question but what do i need to put in                                                     if (hasUnmountedRef) {

      return;
    }

Comment: @KubaKluzniak it's just a guard clause. It stops you from executing the rest of the function. It should have "return" and nothing else.

Comment: (Made some additional fixes to use the ref or the ref value in the correct places)

Comment: Do you know the reason why the custom hook cannot return directly hasUnmountedRed.current? Is it because when we use the custom Hook the value that is saved is not dynamic because of const and only .current can change?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `React.useRef` for that:

In your component:

```
const hasUnmounted = React.useRef(false);

React.useEffect(() => {

 // maybe you have your side effects here, so you can use the boolean to avoid 
 // state updates when the component is unmounted

 if(!hasUnmounted.current) {
  // do state update 
 }
 return () => {
  hasUnmounted.current = true;
 }
}, [])
```

`React.useRef` is suitable to solve this issue as it is very different from changing the state of your component, this is kind of like instance variables in class components, changing this won't trigger a rerender.

Comment: and in state update put my both functions ?

Comment: @KubaKluzniak You mean to call the functions that send/fetch some data and update the state? Yes.

Comment: its not working form me , when i put  this functions it execute them after putinning data

Comment: It depends on how you're using the boolean, you can, for example, have the `useEffect` in your component but use the boolean inside another function which is outside the `useEffect` but is inside the component.

Comment: This useEffect will trigger on every single render because it has no dependency array. I don't think you want that. I think you forgot to include the empty dependency array.

Comment: @jonS90 my intention is to show that we can use `useRef` hook to avoid state updates when the component is unmounted. The usage of `useEffect` depends on the OP.